# How to embed this video - connection failed application rejected connection rtmp

Tags: video, rtmp

I spent over 2 hours to embed this video but I couldn't can someone help me please.

I tried everything I know but I am not successful.

any help will be really appreciated

```
http://up4free.com/stream.php?id=channel9
```